# ListView is missing a Queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have several models in my Django project :

- a User model, (from builtin User class )  : attributes username, first_name, last_name etc
- a Course model, with course properties
- PurchasedCourses model, with users that purchased the course

In my Dbeaver SQL program i can see the PurchasedCourses SQL Table like this :

[image: PurchasedCourses SQL Table]

User model is builtin and the last two models are listed below .

```
class Course(models.Model):
    course_name=models.CharField(max_length=128)
    description=models.TextField(max_length=500,blank=True)
    course_level=models.TextChoices('course_level', 'Beginner Intermediate Advanced')
    level=models.CharField(blank=False, choices=course_level.choices,max_length=20)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('basicapp:course_detail',kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.course_name

class PurchasedCourses(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course=models.ForeignKey(Course,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    purchase_date=models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name+ "_" +self.user.last_name+"_"+self.course.course_name.replace(" ","_")
```

I want for a user based on his id to get a HTML template with the user's purchased courses. So , I created a **PurchasedCoursesView** where i override the get_queryset() method to show only the purchased courses belonging to that user.

**basicapp/views.py:**

```
from django.views.generic import ListView,
from . import models
                              
class PurchasedCoursesView(ListView):
   context_object_name='my_courses'
   models=models.PurchasedCourses
   template_name='basicapp/my_courses.html'

  def get_queryset(self,*args,**kwargs):
       qs=super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
       qs=qs.filter(user_id=self.request.user.id)
       return qs
```

**basicapp/urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path
from basicapp import views

app_name='basicapp'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
    path(r'my_courses/',views.PurchasedCoursesView.as_view(),name='my_courses'),
]
```

I get the error that the queryset is empty and i don't know why . My models are populated with entries in my database:

[image: error geting view]

Comment: You need to use `model = models.PurchasedCourses`. Otherwise the `super().get_queryset()` will indeed raise an error.

Comment: of course, corrected and it worked . big thumbs up. Thank You